# How-to get the Application path using javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have my application hosted in a directory. The application path is the directory name.

For example

`http://192.168.1.2/AppName/some.html`

How to get using javascript the application name like in my case `/AppName`.

`document.domain` is returning the hostname and `document.URL` is returning the whole Url.

**EDIT**

Thr app path could be more complex, like `/one/two/thre/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will give you a result but would have to be modified if you have more levels (see commented code).

```
var path = location.pathname.split('/');
if (path[path.length-1].indexOf('.html')>-1) {
  path.length = path.length - 1;
}
var app = path[path.length-2]; // if you just want 'three'
// var app = path.join('/'); //  if you want the whole thing like '/one/two/three'
console.log(app);
```

Comment: That will work fine, as long as the page is not served from a default document: `http://192.168.1.2/AppName/`

Comment: You're right. I've updated the code. However it only covers '.html' and would have to be modified if you have a different extension. Maybe having it look for '.' would be enough for most people?

Answer (score 15):

```
window.location.pathname.substr(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

Comment: This worked well for my scenario after I changed the lastIndexOf to "/swagger" not a perfect solution, but the best one for my case and simple. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(p) {
    var s = p.split("/").reverse();
    s.splice(0, 1);
    return s.reverse().join("/");
})(location.pathname)
```

This is an expression... just copy-paste it to the place where you need that string.
Or put it in a variable, so that you can use it multiple times.

Comment: Returns an error. 'pathName' should be all lowercase. It also doesn't satisfy the app path based on update to original question (otherwise a very smart solution).

Comment: Yes, of course ... lowercase. However, it does not throw an error, but returns undefined.

Comment: I updated the code. Now it is in form of an function expression that executes and returns the desired string value...

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
function getAppPath() {
    var pathArray = location.pathname.split('/');
    var appPath = "/";
    for(var i=1; i<pathArray.length-1; i++) {
        appPath += pathArray[i] + "/";
    }
    return appPath;
}

alert(getAppPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert("/"+location.pathname.split('/')[1]);`

If your path is something like /myApp/...

or

```
function applicationContextPath() {
    if (location.pathname.split('/').length > 1)
        return "/" + location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    else
        return "/";
}
alert(applicationContextPath);
```