# How to get the application name by code?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can I get the application name by javascript code in a Windows 8 based app?

EDIT: Being more precise: I want the String in package.appxmanifest -> Application UI -> Display name

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677338/how-to-get-the-application-path-using-javascript

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted... see edited version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marco's answer was helpful, but converting to Javascript proved slightly difficult because of the poorly documented XML namespace requirement. LINQ-to-XML as with XDocument isn't available in WinJS but was used in Marco's referenced C# resource.

Here's how I got the app name. Note that it is asynchronous; AFAIK there is no synchronous way to get the application name.

```
var appname; 

(function() {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync("AppxManifest.xml").then(function(file) {
        Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).done(function (text) {
            var xdoc = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
            xdoc.loadXml(text);
            appname = xdoc.selectNodesNS("m:Package/m:Applications/m:Application/m:VisualElements",
                "xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest\"")[0]
                .attributes.getNamedItem("DisplayName").nodeValue;
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: This is awesome! I was able to edit this to get out the app capabilities. It's somewhat ridiculous that there is no built in WinJS API to get this sort of information out. Makes it hard to make a redistributable control that needs a specific capability, with no good way to tell the consuming developer that the host app is configured incorrectly.

Comment: The Displayname is also in can also be found under the DisplayName property. Still way to complicated but a little shorter selector (didn't get yours to work using VS Express 2013 for Windows) Code: xdoc.selectNodesNS("m:Package/m:Properties/m:DisplayName", "xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest\"")[0].innerText;

Answer (score 5):

```
var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current;
var displayName = package.displayName;
```

Added in 8.1

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with localized displaynames via resources.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winappswithcsharp/thread/1ac548fc-0b83-49b9-bb6b-3eabef5024c3), there is no way to get the display name.  You can get the package name from [Package.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.id.aspx), but it sounds like you want the display name.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to the [AppManifestHelper](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/Common/AppManifestHelper.cs) class that is included in the Callisto Control Toolikit. The **GetManifestVisualElementsAsync** method returns a **VisualElement** object with the property **DisplayName**, that is what you're looking for.

Note that this code is in C#, so you need to convert it to Javascript.